# htaccess With a different amount of variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, get, url-rewriting

I have a website that on one specific page it requires an extra variable.

At the moment, the htaccess I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which works fine with one variable.

How would I get it to work with :
http://tessite.com/index.php?page=test&id=1

So it looked like:
http://tessite.com/test/1

Thanks for any help or replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Just add `$2`!

Also, `[^/]` isn't required, you can simply use `.`.

Comment: The only problem now, is when I go to a page that does not require the second variable, it does not work.

Comment: Just add another line with with only the first variable (updated my code above)

Answer (score 6):

It can be coded like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```