# htaccess With a different amount of variables - part 2

Tags: variables, url-rewriting, rule

i need a rewrite rule for URLs which contains sometime 1 and sometimes 2 variables.

example:

```
my.domain.de/Start 
my.domain.de/Help/Browser
```

i have set up two rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?do=$1&sub=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesnt'work. Some parts of the website are displayed, but stylesteets won't load anymore.

The problem with two variables was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770035/htaccess-with-a-different-amount-of-variables), but this solution doesn't work for me.

The solution in the mentioned thread was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If i try this rules, error object not found is displayed.

if i set only this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and delete the first /

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

it works for 1 variable. But this is like my own solution andy now i have no idea how to fix this problem...

Any idea?

PS: i use xampp in the current version

Thanks a lot
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by myself

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/*([^/\.]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```